# How to add X image over the image for remove in ImageListview dll

Tags: c#, winforms

In my windows application I am using the ImageListView.dll displaying selected images.

I used the following code for Adding the selected images to ImageListView

```
    string folder = Photo_Care.Properties.Settings.Default.LastFolder;
    if (Directory.Exists(folder))
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = folder;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        Properties.Settings.Default.LastFolder = folder;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        imageListView1.Items.AddRange(openFileDialog1.FileNames);
    }
```

And I can able to remove the selected Image from Image List using the below code.

```
    imageListView1.SuspendLayout();

    // Remove selected items
    foreach (var item in imageListView1.SelectedItems)
        imageListView1.Items.Remove(item);

    // Resume layout logic.
    imageListView1.ResumeLayout(true);
```

But Now I want to add the close button right top of the added image instantly for removing the image. Like Below Image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmcDm.png]

Comment: anything u have googled so far?

Comment: You should check out the source code of the library, integrate it on your solution and modify (custom) it by yourself